# bash: tvservice: command not found

Tags: raspbian

I am new to linux and new to raspi. I need some help getting tvservice running. I am using the image from the raspberry thin client project which is based on  raspbian. tvservice is installed.

If I log in via SSH I am able to run the command `tvservice -s`.

If I open a terminal window on the raspi itself and type `tvservice -s` I get bash: tvservice: command not found

I also tried to su first the same result.

I dont know where to look. Can anybody help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Note that I somewhat copy edited your post. If you feel that unneccessary you can always revert that edit. Also find my answer which addresses the issue.

Comment: @Mike Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy libraspberrypi-bin` ?

Comment: @Mike, could you please check `echo $PATH` both logged in via ssh and local terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`tvservice` is not in `$PATH`, which is why you get the "command not found" message. Your shell simply does not find it. On my Pi it sits in `/opt/vc/bin`.

To run it type: `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s` using its full path.

Comment: Thanks the path /opt/vc/bin/ does not exists. How can i search for the correct pass

Comment: `find / -name tvservice`. If not run as root mind a lots "Permission denied" messages. If you find it, let me know to update the answer.

Comment: Log in via SSH and type `which tvservice` or `type tvservice` to find the path.

Comment: @bryn, unfortunately `which` *does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed in the environment variable PATH* (man which). So this will not work out, as we already know that it is not in PATH.

Comment: @Ghanima He states the command works fine via SSH, so then it's in PATH.

Comment: @bryn, yes it works on ssh and not with a local shell. So if it were in PATH in both cases it would run and not produce the `command not found` error. It's still possible to have different PATH setting in both cases, e.g.  .bashrc is only sourced if interactive and non-login shell. Anyhow, we're in the dark here, the OP needs to clarify this by running simple tests.

Comment: @Ghanima OP already stated the environment is different. Like I already said he could run `which tvservice` when logged in via SSH, where it works and is in PATH - `which` will work too.

Comment: You're right, I misread your first statement. `which` will do in this case, as will `find`.

Comment: Might be worth checking for a `/opt/vc/sbin`, I vaguely recall having to `sudo` to use it so it may have been a privileged command.

Comment: I like to have the `mlocate` file indexing package installed, once one has done a `sudo updatedb` (and I think it is run as a cron job to keep it up to date) a quick `locate `some executable`| grep bin` can report where something is much faster than repeated `find` instances...

Comment: @SlySven, good call. But then again in this case one has to run `find` just once, add it to $PATH$ and be done ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `tvservice` command used to be part of `libraspberrypi-bin` package, which it contains various utilities for interacting with the Raspberry Pi’s video hardware interfaces (hdmi, camera, vga, etc).  Recent versions of the package (as of Oct 2023) contain another utility which accepts multiple subcommands: `vcgencmd <sudcommand> [<param>]`

You may view the supported subcommands with this:

```shell
$ sudo apt install libraspberrypi-bin  # if not installed
...
$ vcgencmd commands
commands="commands, set_logging, bootloader_config, bootloader_version, cache_flush, ...

# E.g. to switch off screen:
vcgencmd commands display_power 0
```

See [`vcgencmd` documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#vcgencmd) and [source code](https://github.com/raspberrypi/utils/tree/master/vcgencmd).